# How to read in multiple image files (ppm files) in colab (skimage not defined)

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, scikit-image

I'm a complete newbie to Tensorflow and colab. I am currently working through a beginner tutorial. I am working in colab in google.

I'm trying to run the following code in order to read in a number of image files from my google drive directory containing a number of sub-directories.

```
def load_data(data_directory):
    directories = [d for d in os.listdir(data_directory) 
                   if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(data_directory, d))]
    labels = []
    images = []
    for d in directories:
        label_directory = os.path.join(data_directory, d)
        file_names = [os.path.join(label_directory, f) 
                      for f in os.listdir(label_directory) 
                      if f.endswith(".ppm")]
        for f in file_names:
            images.append(skimage.data.imread(f))
            labels.append(int(d))
    return images, labels
```

But I get the following error:

`NameError: name 'skimage' is not defined`

I am not sure if it's because the correct libraries are not loaded. 
Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you actually import skimage?

Comment: I tried, but it still didnt seem to work. Could you perhaps post some code as to how you would import it? Is it a simple import or are there other dependencies?

Comment: No just import it at the top of your script file like `import skimage`. Or can you show your whole script file?

Comment: I did import it as you suggested, but i now get the error `AttributeError: module 'skimage.data' has no attribute 'imread'`, but I have managed to get it working using `cv2.imread()`

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following imports (try both just to be sure):

```
import skimage.io
from skimage import data, io, filters
```